# Ideal in the ring of upper triangular matrices

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I'm trying to describe an ideal of the ring $R=\left\{ \begin{pmatrix}a & b\\
0 & c
\end{pmatrix}:a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}\right\} $
It's easy to prove that $I=\left\{ \begin{pmatrix}0 & a\\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}:a\in\mathbb{R}\right\} $ and $J=\left\{ \begin{pmatrix}a & b\\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}:a,b\in\mathbb{R}\right\} $ are ideals of $R$
My question is: how can I find other ideals?
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I assume that by "ideal" you mean "two sided ideal".

Note that you can independently scale the two columns or the two rows of a matrix by multiplying on one side or the other by a diagonal matrix.  So in a one dimensional ideal the matrices can only have one nonzero entry.  There are three locations for this entry and you can check that of the three, only
$$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & \ast \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
gives an ideal, so this is the only possible $1$ dimensional ideal.  The ring is three dimensional so all that's left are the two dimensional ideals.

A matrix in $R$ is a unit if and only if it has non-zero entries on the diagonal and we're looking for a proper ideal so all our matrices must have a zero on the diagonal.  The ideal must also contain a matrix which has a nonzero on the diagonal (otherwise the ideal is the one dimensional ideal above).  We can scale this nonzero entry to $1$ so our ideal must contain a matrix of the form
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & \ast \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \qquad \text{or} \qquad \begin{pmatrix} 0 & \ast \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
Note it cannot contain one of each because adding them would give a unit.  So all the matrices in the ideal must be of the form
$$\begin{pmatrix} \ast & \ast \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \qquad \text{or} \qquad \begin{pmatrix} 0 & \ast \\ 0 & \ast \end{pmatrix}$$
Now you just have to check that those actually give ideals and then you'll have shown that there are exactly three proper non-trivial ideals.

Comment: If $R$ denotes the original ring, and $J$ denotes the 1-dimensional ideal you pointed out, you could also use the correspondence of ideals between $R/J$ and the ideals of $R$ above $J$ to detect the other two ideals. (It's pretty easy to see that every nonzero ideal has to contain $J$.)

Comment: Thanks so much. But there one thing I don't understand: what is a one dimensional ideal? And for a ring of 2x2 matrix with special form, such as $M=\left\{ \begin{pmatrix}a & b\\
b & a
\end{pmatrix}:a,b\in\mathbb{R}\right\} $ can there be a general way to describe prime (or maximal) ideal of that ring? I have no idea with this problem. Thanks for your help

Comment: @NhutMinh That's a two-dimensional real algebra that isn't a field, so it has to be $\Bbb R\oplus \Bbb R$.

Comment: @NhutMinh You can come up with an explicit mapping too by looking for two idempotents $e,f$ such that $e+f=1$ and $ef=fe=0$, and then mapping them to $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ in $\Bbb R\oplus \Bbb R$.

Comment: @rschwieb I don't understand what you mean, could you explain it?

Comment: @NhutMinh: An ideal must be closed under addition.  As multiplying a matrix by $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}c & 0 \\ 0 & c\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ is the same thing as multiplying a matrix by the scalar $c$ an ideal for this ring must also be closed under scalar multiplication.  Thus ideals are vector spaces and vector spaces have a dimension.  By "one dimensional ideal" I just mean an ideal whose dimension as a vector space over $\mathbb R$ is equal to $1$.

Comment: So this means that upper triangular matrices are PID?

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{pmatrix} a & b\\ 0 & c \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} x & y\\ 0 & z \end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix} ax & ay+bz\\ 0 & cz \end{pmatrix}$.

If $a\neq 0$, you can vary $ax$ and $ay$ over $\mathbb{R}$, by varying $x$ and $y$. Similarly, if $b\neq 0$, you can vary $bz$ over $\mathbb{R}$, and if $c\neq 0$, you can vary $cz$ over $R$ by varying $z$. Thus, the different *right* ideals of $R$ are:

$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \ast \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 & \ast \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 & \ast \\ 0 & \ast \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} \ast & \ast \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} \ast & \ast \\ 0 & \ast \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Ahh, I didn't consider left multiplication. I knew I was missing something. Thanks

Comment: Well, at least these are the right ideals of $R$.